# Re-image disks of an existing vm

Tags: virtual-machine, libvirt, virsh

I am using the libvirt utility to manage vms and I had a specific requirement to restart a vm from scratch i.e. like a fresh bootup, wipe disks clean and restart.

Is that possible with any of the libvirt/virsh commands?

Reset/reboot commands re-init state but retain logs.

Comment: Attach install media (virtual CD or USB storage). Boot from install media. The tricky bit will be automating the install. Optionally you can remove and and a new virtual hard-disk.